# Why Real Numbers are called Real Numbers?

Tags: terminology, definition, real-numbers, math-history

I have been searching on internet for the meaning that why real numbers are called real numbers, I found many information on different websites like in https://www.cuemath.com/numbers/real-numbers/ , it is written, "**Any number that can be found in the real world is a real number**".

On the other hand I found on https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/real-numbers.html (bottom of the page), it is written, "**Real does not mean they are in the real world. They are not called "Real" because they show the value of something real. In mathematics we like our numbers pure, when we write 0.5 we mean exactly half. But in the real world half may not be exact (try cutting an apple exactly in half)**".

So why they are called Real Numbers? What is the reason?

Comment: It distinguishes them from the imaginary numbers.

Comment: With "real" it is meant that they can be found on the number line.

Comment: The real question is, why do we call them "numbers".

Comment: If you ask "why do we use the word orange when talking about the color orange" you might actually get an answer (*it was named after the fruit of the same name*).  If you were to ask the question "why do we use the word red when talking about the color red" the answer might just be that we needed a word to describe the concept and we just happened to call it that out of convenience.

Comment: Graham's number (for example) is too large to have any physical meaning, nevertheless it is still a real number.

Comment: From Wikipedia, both [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number), the adjectives "real" and "imaginary" were both invented by Descartes to discredit complex numbers.

Comment: @TheoBendit I think you could post that as an answer.

Comment: @TheoBendit that's incredibly funny in retrospect, as complex numbers can easily be represented on a Cartesian plane.

Comment: Complex numbers were initially controversial because even negative numbers, let alone their square roots, were, so the latter were called imaginary. Once complex numbers became uncontroversial enough for "old" numbers to need a distinguishing name that hadn't been theretofore necessary, it was natural to call them real, and say each complex number is the sum of a real number and an imaginary number (i.e. $i$ times a real number).

Comment: See Descartes' [Geometrie (1637)](https://download.tuxfamily.org/openmathdep/geometry_analytic/The_Geometry-Descartes.pdf) page 380 French text: "neither the true roots nor the false are always real; sometimes they are, however, imaginary; namely, whereas we can always imagine as many roots for each equation, there is still not always a quantity which corresponds to each root so imagined. Thus, while we may think of the equation $x^{3}- 6xx + 13x - 10 = 0$ as having three roots, yet there is just one real root, which is $2$, ...

Comment: and the other two, however, increased, diminished, or multiplied them as we just laid down, remain always imaginary."